# How to get interface of promise to compare with actual results in tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interface, jasmine, q

Application uses service $q (module ng). Some functions have to return a promise. I need to verify that results have **full** interface of promise.

Not only method *then* (as check Angular and as somebody recommend in answers on stackoverflow): `_.isFunction(myObject.then) === true`.

But full interface of current implementation for the Promise API (according to $q ng) - methods then, catch, finally. E.g.:

```
var hasPromiseInterface = !['then','catch','finally'].some(function (methodName) {
    return !_.isFunction(myObject[methodName]);
});
```

However I don't want to hard-code the list of methods. I want to get them via stable API like this:

```
var promiseInterface = Object.getPrototypeOf($q.when());

var hasPromiseInterface = !_.keys(promiseInterface).some(function (element) {
        return !_.isFunction(value[element]);
    });
```

In this way I use full object (*promiseInterface*) with each function actual implementation. Thus, it is not interface in fact.

Is it possible to somehow get (without hard-code the methods lists) an interface like this:

```
{
    then: angular.noop,
    catch: angular.noop,
    finally: angular.noop
}
```

or like this:

```
{
    then: jasmine.any(Function),
    catch: jasmine.any(Function),
    finally: jasmine.any(Function)
}
```

?

Thank to advance!

P.S. It should be easy readable and laconic way :). It will be better if this way be useful for Deferred interface (resolve, reject, notify) as well.